# Is it Possible to style Table horizontal scrollbar?

Tags: css, reactjs

Is it possible to style horizontal scroll bar in Table, it's so ugly ?

```
import { Row, Col, Modal, Table } from 'reactstrap';
<Table bordered responsive>
...
</Table>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link should be helpful. https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/scrollbar/
jsfiddle for the example: https://jsfiddle.net/prak_mtl/ta3spmgu/5/

```
tableWrapperClassName::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 1em;
}

tableWrapperClassName::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

tableWrapperClassName::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: darkgrey;
  outline: 1px solid slategrey;
}
```

Comment: I have tried this, but it doesn't work. Nothing changes, but there's Pseudo element on my Class that I applied to.

Comment: check the jsfiddle link i added

Comment: Thanks bro, It seems like my responsive class is overriding it. By removing it, I get it to work